# PyBFD cannot find Binutils in 16.04

Tags: package-management, python, 16.04, binutils

I've upgraded my distro from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS. In 15.10 everything was okay. I am using `pybfd 0.1.1` with `binutils 2.26` (In 16.04).

The python package `pybfd` used to be okay with `binutils` of 15.10. But in 16.04 it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: libbfd-2.25.1-system.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems it sill intends to use `binutils` of 15.10. How can I tell it to use `binutils` of 16.10? Is there any update for `pybfd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem!

- Remove current installation of `pybfd` by `pip uninstall pybfd`.
- Clone [my fork](https://github.com/abforce/pybfd) of `pybfd` which fixes the issue on 16.04 onwards. (created a pull request though)
- Install the package by `sudo python setup.py install`.

Update #1: My pull request merged, you can now clone [the original repo](https://github.com/Groundworkstech/pybfd).