# Unable to downgrade Binutils package

Tags: package-management, python, 16.04, binutils

#### The Problem

I'm currently on 16.04 LTS. `binutils` package of this distro is of version 2.26. But I need 2.25 (`binutils` of 15.10).

I'm using `PyBDF 0.1.1` python packages which depends on `binutils 2.25`. Unfortunately that python package isn't getting updated, so I have to downgrade my `binutils`.

#### What I've done with no luck:

- `apt-get install binutils=2.25.1-6ubuntu1`
- "Force Version" is disabled in Synaptic Package Manager.
- Fooling `PyBDF` by creating a soft link for the .SO file that ships with `binutils 2.25` which points to the .SO file of `binutils 2.26`.

#### Related Questions

- [PyBFD cannot find Binutils in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767005/pybfd-cannot-find-binutils-in-16-04)

#### The Question

How can I downgrade the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Wily repositories to your `sources.list` and use Apt preferences as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170079/update-single-package-from-ubuntu-utopic-unicorn-when-running-trusty-tahr/170100#170100). That question is about upgrading a package, but the exact same idea applies for downgrades. However you will need to initially install the Wily version manually (or give it a priority over 1000) to force the downgrade. After the downgrade is done, a priority of 501 on the Wily package will be enough.

Note that since `binutils` contains many important system tools, it would not be surprising if the downgrade caused your system to function incorrectly. In that case you should install a full Wily system.